# IIS 8.5 redirect HTTP URL to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, iis, iis-8.5

Using IIS 8.5 - our website has been live for several months internally on the corporate network with no SSL cert. Users have been accessing the site through the HTTP URL (let call it http://companyapp) .

I have now a HTTPS certificate and when I apply the cert to the website by adding a new binding the HTTPS URL is https://companyapp:8443 and the HTTPS is working from the browser. -Port 443 is already in use on the server for a different (non IIS) application .

However I want to configure IIS so that when the user types the URL  http://companyapp , the browser will go to https://companyapp - Ideally there will be no port number required in the URL.

I want to do this in the most efficient way, so just curious what my options are as I am admin on the server running IIS but I don't have DNS admin rights on the network.
Thanks

Comment: We can configure `http://companyapp` to `https://companyapp:8443`, but not to `https://companyapp` because the browser will connect to port 443...

Comment: OK. I tried to set up a "HTTP redirect" to https://companyapp:8443 but it didn't work.how would you configure it?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module